# Cannot run linux command with CasperJS

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I am trying to run a simple page speed command, using casper js, but it throws me error "can't find psi module". Below you will find the code :

```
const psi = require('psi');

// Get the PageSpeed Insights report
psi('google.com').then(function(data) {
  console.log(data.ruleGroups.SPEED.score);
  console.log(data.pageStats);
});
```

Trying to run the command manually is working absolutely fine, but not via the script. Do you have any suggestions or any other method to run linux command via CasperJS ?